# Stop queue of functions attached to submit event

Tags: javascript

I have a form and there are 2 different functions attached to it's submit event (see code below).

```
// #1. that part of code does basic client side validation
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});

// #2. ajax request based on filled data on form
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post(...); // AJAX request
});
```

What I want is to avoid AJAX logic (function #2) if validation (function #1) has not passed.

Is it possible to stop queue and if so - how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge the 2 functions in a single one, like this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        $.post(...); // AJAX request
    }
});
```

or in a shorter way:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
        $.post(...); // AJAX request
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, however that is not what I am looking for :(
I could have some forms that only need validation and some that only need submit and some need both: validation + submission.

Comment: I also want to be able to keep logic separately for validation and submit.
but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi With 1 function, you make the validation and the submission all at once. It avoids the pain of cancelling event bubbling,...

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi Also, having 2 functions needs you to know in which order it will be called...